# Keep track of first node in line of nodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've set up my game to have the same node repeatedly added from the bottom with different texture to move up to the top of the screen. I need a method to keep track of the node always leading this line of nodes. So if the original first node gets removed, the one behind it takes its place as the first node and I'm able to keep track of it. This is the code I've used to create my line of nodes. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I tried making an SKNode and placing it above the ball to check its name but it just returns nil.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var aboveNode = SKNode()
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    var create = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.createBottomTargets()})
            var wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(2)
            var createAndWait = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([create, wait]))
            self.runAction(createAndWait, withKey: "firstBottom")

    }

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

println("\(aboveNode.name)")
}

     func createBottomTargets() {

            ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blue1")

            ball.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: -50)

            ball.texture = textures[random]

            self.addChild(ball)

      let move = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 1400, duration: 18)

            let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

            ball.runAction(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]))

        aboveNode.position = CGPoint(x: ball.position.x, y: ball.position.y + 163)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how other parts of your game works, you could set it up so that each subsequent node is a child node of the node before it.  That way the child nodes will move with their parent nodes.  Imagine a vertical stack of nodes set up this way, each of which is 50px tall.  Each node has a local position of [0, 50] to place it atop its parent.  If you remove the bottom node and add it's child nodes back to the scene, all of the descendent nodes will appear to have moved down because their position is relative to their parent node.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I wouldn't be able to do this since it would interfere with some other code. I've added something else I tried in my question, maybe you'd know the solution